# Magento How to Change Validation Custom error message

Tags: magento2, validation

In Magento 2 How to change Sign up Error message

I want to change this **`Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters.`** Where i need to change this error message

[image]

Comment: You can check all error messages in root/lib/web/mage/validation.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution and it worked for me.
Add `data-validate='{"telephone-check-maximum-length-15":true}'` in your input tag. And add below javascript at the end of your phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery', // jquery Library
    'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
    'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
    'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
    $.validator.addMethod(
        'telephone-check-maximum-length-15', function (value) {
            return (value.length<15); // Validation logic here
            },
        $.mage.__('Please enter less or equal than 15 digits.')
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Kazim

I have to change the error div position in footer newsletter " footer_newsletter " subscription to top of the input box, can you suggest me how can i do it .  

"footer_newsletter-error" is new dynamically appends to input box.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which worked for me to changing the message of password field. It might help you in your direction.I have created script rather than overriding entire validation.js. I have added new function and replace error with new. As magento2 is using jquery validation. I have taken this function from validation.js

```
require([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/ui',
            'jquery/validate',
            'mage/translate'
        ], function($){
            $('#password').attr('data-validate', $('#password').attr('data-validate').replace('validate-customer-password','validate-customer-password-custom'));
            $.validator.addMethod(
                'validate-customer-password-custom', function(v, elm) {
                var validator = this,
                    length = 0,
                    counter = 0;
                var passwordMinLength = $(elm).data('password-min-length');
                var passwordMinCharacterSets = $(elm).data('password-min-character-sets');
                var pass = $.trim(v);
                var result = pass.length >= passwordMinLength;
                if (result == false) {
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols." +
                        " Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored."
                    ).replace('%1', passwordMinLength);
                    return result;
                }
                if (pass.match(/\d+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (counter < passwordMinCharacterSets) {
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1." +
                        " Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."
                    ).replace('%1', passwordMinCharacterSets);
                }
                return result;
            }, function () {
                return this.passwordErrorMessage;
            });
        });
```

Here is more detail about this solution [on my own blog](https://blog.m2doctor.com/change-validation-custom-error-message-magento2/) and entire module for this [on my Github repository](https://github.com/m2doctor/Validation)